# Is it appropriate to ask for a friend of a friend?

Tags: discussion

Some questions here might be of a nature which would bring the author into  difficulties with his current employer. Is it therefore acceptable to ask such questions here in the name of a friend?

Comment: Are you talking about asking questions for the benefit of a friend, or asking questions for the benefit of a "friend" (nudge-nudge, wink-wink)?

Comment: It's about questions which fall into the category: I want to ask that, my employer won't like reading such a question, but it's still not so sensitive that I'd need complete anonymity by a throw away account.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone can ask a question anonymously by [creating a throwaway account](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/can-you-add-an-ask-anonymously-feature-for-stack-exchange-sites-like-this-and-on). Just click the 'log out' button at the top of the site, and ask away -- it won't be tied to your main account if you don't want it to be.

If, for whatever reason, the person wants to ask this through your account for whatever reason, realize that you are not anonymous, and depending on how much trouble the person could get in to for the information in the question, the information is still not 100% anonymous because it is still attached to your name.

So I would suggest:

1. If possible, have your friend's friend create a throwaway account to ask the question so that they can put it in their own words and respond to comments/questions if they come up without having to go through you.
2. If not possible, be sure that your post is a good question, follows the rules in the help center, and that your friend is willing to answer questions to it through you if clarification is required

As discussed in a [separate meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1947/7945):

> there should always be enough information. A hypothetical question should be fine, but if there isn't enough "information" (or a detailed enough description of the problem), then it becomes unanswerable anyway. There will be too many possible answers to the question and the whole thread will become a discussion.
>
> We avoid these questions that are too broad, regardless of whether they are hypothetical, because they don't work well in Stack Exchange's model. The format sorts just one answer to the top, but everyone sees many answers they like. It becomes a poll or popularity contest instead of narrowing down on one real answer.

That is about hypothetical questions, but a question asked on behalf of a friend-of-a-friend is quite similar.